# Unable to find BLE heartrate service devices using DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am running [BLE heart rate client side sample application](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bluetooth-Generic-5a99ef95).

A BLE server with HRS service is paired before running the app.

Now, when I run the app the number of devices enumerated using `FindAllAsync` using the statement

```
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(
    GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(GattServiceUuids.HeartRate),
    new string[] { "System.Devices.ContainerId" });
```

is 0.

However when I try finding all the devices using

```
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync();
```

My BLE device with HeatRate service is listed.

How can I short list the BLE device among all the Devices?

Comment: You could try using a Watcher instead to find only devices with a Heart Rate service. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.createwatcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a issue with driver.

My laptop did not have Windows LE enumerator.

I am able to find devices using FindAllAsync after I switched to a laptop with Windows LE enumerator